# Searching for XML elements with XDocument

Tags: xml, linq-to-xml

I'm searching for two elements (supportsA, supportsB) in an XML file.

- I have no way of knowing under which parent element they exist.
- One, both, or none of the elements might exist

Here's one example where they both exist:

```
<ovw ...>
    <supports>
        <supportsA/>
        <supportsB/>
    </supports>
    ...
```

Here's my attempt after reading a couple of articles on SO:

```
var vSupportsA = (from d in doc.Descendants()
where d.Name.LocalName == "supportsA"
select d.Value).First();

var vSupportsB = (from d in doc.Descendants()
where d.Name.LocalName == "supportsB"
select d.Value).First();

if (vSupportsA != null && vSupportsB != null) {
    // supportsA *and* supportsB
}
else if (vSupportsA != null) {
    // supportsA only
}
else if (vSupportsB != null) {
    // supportsB only
}
else {
    // neither element found
}
```

Clearly, I'm doing something wrong as I'm getting an error stating "Sequent contains no elements". Unfortunately, I have no idea what that means.

Comment: Please show a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem - but you want `FirstOrDefault` rather than `First` if you think that the elements might not exist. Also, it's much simpler to use `doc.Descendants("supportsA")` rather than look at the local name of each element - unless you really don't care about the namespaces and think there may be different namespaces involved.

Comment: @JonSkeet: The only thing you're not seeing is the document load, which is working. I get the exception on the first call.

Comment: @JonSkeet: I tried using doc.Descendants("supportsA"). That doesn't throw an exception, but it also doesn't find the element.

Comment: @JonSkeet: Got it to work! Since I can't copy code here (or answer my own question), I'll try and update with a comment. I removed the call to First and simply select d (not d.value). I then check vSupportsA.Count (as opposed to checking for null).

Comment: Well there are definitely better approaches than that, to be honest. Selecting `Value` and using `FirstOrDefault`, for example.